# Have each user have a model attached to them, and that model has a many to one relationship with items

Tags: django

I am trying to create a Django application where each User has one model attached to them ( a list of Plants ) and that model is composed of individual plants. I already know I can have the plants connected to the plant list through a many-to-one relationship using foreign key as shown down below:

```
class PlantList(models.Model):
    plant_list_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Plant(models.Model):
    plantlist = models.ForeignKey(PlantList, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    wateringInterval = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

However, I want each user to have a plant list attached to them that can be displayed uniquely for each user, according to the plants that they add to their list. How would I make it so that each user has a plant list?

I was trying to have it inside the register form but couldn't figure out how to do it and I wanted each plantlist to have a unique ID so that I can add plants to it easier.

```
class AddNewPlant(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name',max_length = 20)
    wateringInterval = forms.IntegerField(label='Watering Interval')
```

Comment: each will have one plant list or multiple?

Comment: @SırrıKırımlıoğlu only one

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you don't need the model `PlantList`.

What you should do instead is: set a `ForeignKey` to the `User Model` inside the `Plant Model`, and in that foreign_key set a `related_name='plants'`.

To access the User Model use:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
```

code example:

```
class Plant(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='plants')
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    wateringInterval = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

Then you can access all user's plants using:

```
first_user = get_user_model().objects.first().plants
```

Comment: I've added what my form to add plants looks like. What would I add to the form so that User is now being referenced?

Comment: This way every plant only may have one owner.

Comment: @SırrıKırımlıoğlu yes, I thought that was what he wanted, your answer is the correct one.

Comment: @mendespedro yeah, that may be what he wants. you are correct, too. I just thought that way it would be an interesting app. LoL

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class User(models.Model):
     plant_list = models.ForeignKey(PlantList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

this is for connecting plant_list with the user. Also, you need to change the relationship between plant and plant_list, so that users can have the same plants as well like below:

```
class Plant(models.Model):
     plantlist = models.ManyToManyField(PlantList)
```

that way different users can have the same plants on their plant_list and every user has only one plant_list.